# Downwards upon us - is it above or below then?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

Reading a story, I found the following sentence:

> Downwards upon us, with limbless Atlantean stridings, there swept the
> cloudy cohorts.

I am struggling with understanding of the phrase "downwards upon" - is it the direction (in downward direction but upon us) or a place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "downward" and "downwards" (adverb) would mean the same thing here. And yes, it indicates direction.
Put another way the sentence might read:

"The cloudy cohorts, with limbless Atlantean stridings, swept downward (s) upon us."